# how to register a selectionProvider for the Viewer from a superclass

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I have a View which extends a View provided by another plugin like this:

```
public class View2 extends some.other.package.View1
{
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) 
    {  
        super.createPartControl(parent);  
        //I want to do this, but I can't because its private  
        //getSite().setSelectionProvider(treeViewer);  
    }  
}
```

But I can't edit the super class, so I need to access the viewer from the Control.

```
public class some.other.package.View1 extends ViewPart
{  
    private TreeViewer treeViewer;  
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {  
        treeViewer = new TreeViewer(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL);  
    }  
}
```

I tried using `parent.getChildren();` to get a `Tree` object, but I can't see that it can be coerced into an `ISElectionProvider` as required

Answer (score 1):

Isn't there some getter which would allow you to get this Treeviewer?
Anyway, if there's not, then the only way to get it that comes to my mind is by using reflection.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try, like in [this class](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/dltk-commits/msg04365.html):

```
ISelectionProvider provider = site.getSelectionProvider();
if (provider instanceof TreeViewer) {
   ...
```

Comment: the selectionProvider for the site is null, because the superclass did not register the Viewer as a selectionProvider - in fact this is the reason that I am extending the class so i can add the viewer as a selectionProvider and use the selected objects in my other View objects...

Answer (score 0):

There is an init method that passes in the IViewSite, on which you can set the selection provider (inherited from IWorkbenchPartSite).